# How could I get my own vote activity from API?

Tags: support, voting, api

For the sake of curiosity I want to visualize my vote activity on Stack Overflow. I can scrape it easily from HTML, but it would be elegant to accomplish it using an API.

Comment: [You can't](//stackapps.com/questions/4725/list-of-votes-by-authenticated-users), but [many would like to be able to](//stackapps.com/questions/2850/2-0-api-get-votes).